# Using VBA to Merge Data

Tags: excel, vba

Goes directly to MsgBox without seemingly changing anything.

I've been playing around with this code for awhile now since I'm new to VBA. I'm aware this script isn't pointed at a specific spreadsheet.

```
Private Sub MergeData()

'The cell it will use to search
Dim idCheck As Range
'The cell it will use to compare text
Dim currentCell As Range
'The cell is will use to compare duplicates
Dim oneRowBelow As Range
'Will briefly say if something changed in furthest column
Dim changes As String
'This will be used to format the "Changes" column
Dim rowNumberValue As Integer, columnNumberValue As Integer, rowBelow As Integer

colNum = 3
rowNumberValue = ActiveCell.Row
columnNumberValue = ActiveCell.Column
rowBelow = ActiveCell.Row + 1

'Searches by ID column
For Each idCheck In Worksheets("Test").Range("B2:B1000")
   'This checks to find duplicate ID rows
   If idCheck.Value = idCheck.Offset(-1, 0).Value Then
         'Goes from each column starting from the ID column (H = 7th letter in alphabet and H is the last column)
         'Technically S is the last column since S just lists what has changed
         For colNum = 3 To 7

            'Checks to see if the current cell has no value but the duplicate cell does
            If Cells(rowNumberValue, colNum) = "" And Cells(rowBelow, colNum) <> "" Then
               'Changes current cell value to the duplicate cell value
               Cells(rowNumberValue, colNum) = Cells(rowBelow, colNum)

               'Writes in the 19th column whether or not data has been changed
               changes = "Added"
               Cells(rowNumberValue, 19) = changes
               Cells(rowNumberValue, 19).Interior.ColorIndex = 4
            End If

            'Checks to see if current cell has value but the duplicate cell doesn't
            If Cells(rowNumberValue, colNum) <> "" And Cells(rowBelow, colNum) = "" Then
               'Merges the two cells ( Unfortunately .Merge takes the top cell value only)
               Range(Cells(rowNumberValue, colNum), Cells(rowBelow, colNum)).Merge

               'Writes in the 19th column whether or not data has been changed
               changes = "Added"
               Cells(rowNumberValue, 19) = changes
               Cells(rowNumberValue, 19).Interior.ColorIndex = 4
            End If

            'Checks to see if the cell value is different from the duplicate value
            If Cells(rowNumberValue, colNum) <> Cells(rowBelow, colNum) Then
               'This just sets the first value to the duplicate value (since it doesn't matter which one is overwritten)
               Cells(rowBelow, colNum) = Cells(rowNumberValue, colNum)

               'Writes in the 19th column whether or not data has been changed
               changes = "Changed"
               Cells(rowNumberValue, 19) = changes
               Cells(rowNumberValue, 19).Interior.ColorIndex = 6

            End If
         Next colNum
    End If
    colNum = 3
Next
    MsgBox "All done"
End Sub
```

So for example, if two rows have the number 123 in their ID column, and the Name column in the first row lists Timothy and the second row lists Tim, the script should change the row to say Bob and say in the furthest column what was changed. Or, if the first or second row has an empty cell while the other row doesn't, the data from the non-empty cell would be merged/copied over to the empty one.

It doesn't matter which data is overwritten, as long as all empty cells that can be filled, are filled.

Comment: If nothing is happening, then you have 2 scenarios, the overarching if-condition is false or all three internal if-conditions are false.  Looking at your variables, you have declared your variables OUTSIDE of the loop, so things like `rowNumberValue` are not updated as you iterate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From my comment, I believe you're causing false conditions due to where your variables are defined:

```
'Searches by ID column
For Each idCheck In Worksheets("Test").Range("B2:B1000")
    'find current cell's row to be used in if-statements
    rowNumberValue = ActiveCell.Row  'MOVED INTO ROW LOOP ==============
    rowBelow = ActiveCell.Row + 1  'MOVED INTO ROW LOOP ==============
   'This checks to find duplicate ID rows
   If idCheck.Value = idCheck.Offset(-1, 0).Value Then
         'Goes from each column starting from the ID column (H = 7th letter in alphabet and H is the last column)
         'Technically S is the last column since S just lists what has changed
         For colNum = 3 To 7 'COLNUM IS DEFINED, NOT NEEDED BEFOREHAND ==========
             columnNumberValue = ActiveCell.Column 'if you need this, put it inside of this section, but you shouldn't need it due to colNum existing =========
             'Your other code here
         Next colNum
    End If
Next
```

You also don't need to reset, manually, your `colNum` to 3 at the end, due to the `For` loop doing that when it iterates.

Flagged my comments/changes in your code with `========` after the comments.

Comment: It seems to be working, however in one of the columns (Specifically H(7)), since it's a column with zip codes, it's not merging because it's an integer and not a string. Any ideas? Also it only works when I manually select 2 duplicates.

Comment: Never mind, I know why the zip code isn't working, I was just selecting 8 columns, not 7, not sure on the selection thing still.